# Защищенное снятие дампа

Tags: база-данных, postgresql, mysql

Ситуация такая: база данных содержит особо чувствительную информацию, разглашение которой крайне нежелательно. Сотрудник (администратор), снимающий дамп, является доверенным лицом. Тем не менее, есть потребность повысить защищенность системы таким образом, чтобы администратор мог снимать дамп, но не мог смотреть данные базы. Возможно ли это и если да, то как это сделать? База - либо MySQL, либо PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 1):

Ни MySQL, ни PostgreSQL не имеют встроенного механизма снятия зашифрованных дапмов. Поэтому можно предложить такой подход: создать скрипт, снимающий и шифрующий дамп, например, для PostgreSQL,

```
pg_dumpall > databasegzip databaseencrypt database.gzmv database.gz.enc target
```

При этом ограничить права пользователя, только запуском скрипта и просмотром целевой папки. Но вообще надежность и защищенность такого подхода в реальности вызывает сомнения.